# phpseclib zero byte padding

Tags: php, encryption, phpseclib, 3des

How to add zero byte padding in phpseclib with encryption method 3des in EBC mode?

Here my current code:

```
$cipher = new TripleDES(TripleDES::MODE_ECB);
$cipher->setKey('1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMN');
```

Comment: How about `$cipher->enablePadding();`? Since `TripleDES` extends `DES` extends `BlockCipher` extends `SymmetricKey`, you might use the `enablePadding()` function defined in `SymmetricKey` class: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/Common/SymmetricKey.php. Didn't actually try, though.

Comment: can we customize padding character in enablePadding method?

for example $cipher -> enablePadding('\0');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figure it out:

1. Disable padding:

   ```
   $cipher->disablePadding();
   ```
2. Manually pad message:

   ```
   $message_padded = $urlencoded;
   if (strlen($message_padded) % 8) {
       $message_padded = str_pad($message_padded,
           strlen($message_padded) + 8 - strlen($message_padded) % 8, "\0");
   }
   ```
3. encrypt:

   ```
   $result = $cipher -> encrypt($message_padded);
   ```

Comment: Your approach looks okay, but why do you want to do so? Btw, you can add a new method to wrap the above codes, so that you can reuse the customized padding method easily.

Comment: 1. Because there is a service(partner) that require the enryption method above.
2. I'll try it, thank you for the advice